# Error response from daemon: network bridge not found

Tags: postgresql, networking, docker, containers, bridge

I just got these messages after starting my docker service on ubuntu 14.04, and trying to starting the postgres container.

```
$ docker start codeslave-postgres --> starting my container
$ Error response from daemon: network bridge not found
$ Error: failed to start containers: codeslave-postgres
```

I was try to stop and restart docker service and also restart my machine too but it seems doesn't work enough. so what are these message means ?

Answer (score 6):

Based on what i found on here [docker issues](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/18113)

The people says there is a file on `/var/lib/docker/network/files/local-kv.db`, so deleting the file might be work for you if you got error related to network bridge.

Then i try to delete that `local-kv.db` file and restarting my docker service and it's now worked.

**NOTE:** - If you can't find the file on that path, try to do `sudo su` first, make you super user to see and do the rest.